# How can you obtain a current manifest from the playhead in AV player?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayer

I am currently trying to capture the currently playing HLS/DASH manifest in the AV player.

Would anyone have any code snippets/documentation that could help with it?

Answer (score 1):

To access the current url that the avplayer is streaming from:

```
if let currAsset = player.currentItem.asset as? AVURLAsset {
    var url = currAsset.url
    ... use the url ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any official documentation about this either. I suppose then at the time of writing that `AVPlayer` does not provide the manifest.

Failing that, consider downloading the playlist and parse the manifest by your own.

I found [M3U8Kit](https://github.com/M3U8Kit/M3U8Parser) useful to parse m3u8 manifest.